# Command Substitution in bash shell, when the command itself has a quote

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Im trying to extract the last line of a text file using sed and move it to a variable. However, command substitution using quotes breaks the sed command which already uses quotes.

```
sed '$!d' cookie.txt
```

Returns: `localhost FALSE   /XSS/   FALSE   ******      loggedIn    No`

However, trying to move it to a variable, like so:

```
varin='sed '$!d' cookie.txt'
```

provides no output for the variable $varin

For PHP, we can have nested quotes using double and single quotes, is there anything similar here?

Comment: Lazy suggestion at being helpful: Did you try escaping the inner backquotes by placing a \ in front of them? See if this is a step in the right direction: `varin='sed \'$!d\' cookie.txt'`

Comment: the variable is shell variable?

Comment: Never use backquotes in `bash`. `$(...)` is far superior.

Comment: @Kent:Yes, the variable is a shell variable

Comment: @n.m: I had tried that, but variable=$(..) gives a localhost:command not found output

Comment: By the way you don't seem to have any backquotes in the posted code.

Comment: @Jarmund: Nope, bash waits for a new line when I try that

Comment: Then you probably should investigate *that* error and not anything that involves backquotes.

Comment: @MklRjv: It's vitally important when asking for help with something like this that you report the command you're using *accurately*, and follow the suggestions *exactly*. In your question it appears you've swapped backquotes into normal quotes, and it also appears you've tried something other than Mark's suggested `$( ... )` syntax. The people here are trying to help you; please don't make it difficult for them.

Comment: Terribly sorry for the confusion. I had gotten the backquote confused with the normal quote. But my system does not seem to accept the $(...) syntax, as it throws an error. Mark's tail command suggestion helped me out though. It seems my shell is pretty outdated as I am using a really old version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var=$(tail -1 cookie.txt)
```

or with sed:

```
var=$(sed '$!d' cookie.txt)
```

Comment: $(...) doesnt seem to work, but, var='tail -1 cookie.txt', does what I want. Thank you for this suggestion. For some strange reason the $(..) gives a localhost:command not found error.

Comment: `$(...) doesnt seem to work` --- you probably have something that is not bash, or an extremely outdated version of bash.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting an error like "localhost:command not found" with `$(...)`, it sounds like you are nesting backticks inside the command substitution, like

```
variable=$(`sed '$!d' cookie.txt`)
```

The backticks would run the `sed` command to produce the string beginning with "localhost", then because that string is inside `$(...)`, *it* would be treated as a command to run. Simply using

```
variable=$( sed '$!d' cookie.txt )
```

should do what you want.